# SQL Server Express 2008 R2 reduce size

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to reduce the size of your mdf file?

So far I have used DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(0) but it made very little difference.

I've searched for links everywhere, but as a beginner I'm finding it difficult to understand the terminology.

Comment: why do you think you need to reduce size of .mdf file?

Comment: Can you execute sp_spaceused and give us the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Management studio execute the code below

```
sp_spaceused
GO
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE('yourdatabasename')
GO
sp_spaceused
```

Your database now will be shrinked by the number of free space given from the first sp_spaceused execution

Also check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190488.aspx